# Ionic 2, Xcode and JSON: Unable to display JSON data

Tags: json, xcode, typescript, ionic-framework

I am successfully able to extract JSON data from a JSON file embedded into my project and view data when using "ionic serve" on my machine. (This works locally on my Mac using ionic serve)
I am having an issue after building for IOS in XCode.
I import the generated project into XCode (As I have successfully done in the past) but the JSON is no longer visible when running in XCode or when running on my IPhone.

I am running the latest version of everything and working on a mac.

Can someone please show me what I may be doing wrong or what I am missing?

Thanks again for any help!!!

I am including snippets of my code below:

```
**src/assets/data/kjv.json**
JSON file location

**src/providers/my-data/my-data.ts:**
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyData {

    constructor(public http: Http) {
    }

    getLocalData(){
        return this.http.get('../../assets/data/kjv.json');
    }

}

**src/pages/home/home.ts:**
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyData } from '../../providers/my-data/my-data';
import { ChaptersPage } from '../chapters/chapters';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    items: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public myService: MyData) {
    }

    ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.myService.getLocalData().map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data         => {
        this.items = data;
        });
    }

    nextPage(bookNo){
        localStorage.setItem('bookNumber', bookNo);
        this.navCtrl.push(ChaptersPage);
    }

}

**src/app/app.module.ts:**
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ChaptersPage } from '../pages/chapters/chapters';
import { VersesPage } from '../pages/verses/verses';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { MyData } from '../providers/my-data/my-data';

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        ChaptersPage,
        VersesPage,
        TabsPage
        ],
        imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        HttpModule
        ],
        bootstrap: [IonicApp],
        entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        AboutPage,
        ContactPage,
        HomePage,
        ChaptersPage,
        VersesPage,
        TabsPage
        ],
        providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
        MyData
        ]
    })
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was pointing to the location of the JSON file.
This solved my problem:

this.http.get('../../assets/data/kjv.json');

was changed to,

this.http.get('assets/data/kjv.json');

Thanks to nuttloose from the ionic forums...